# Get current, "real" frames-per-second (fps) of a running Flash movie?

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

What is the best way to get the current, "real" frames-per-second of a running Flash movie using Actionscript 2?  By "best", I mean it should be accurate over a period of time (i.e. it does some averaging) and with a minimal built-in performance overhead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same method that you would apply to AS3. You can't copy + paste AS3 code in an AS2 movie, but shouldn't be too difficult to port. Try porting [stats](http://code.google.com/p/mrdoob/wiki/stats) from Mr Doob.

Cheers.